# Is there a way to play a clean start in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm trying to play a game from scratch, that is with zero badass points and zero in everything else, but I can't seem to be able to, every time I load the game, it downloads the files from the cloud and my saved files are there again.

Is there a way to play a clean start in Borderlands 2?

Comment: Disable cloud saves then...

Comment: Could you direct me as to how to do this? EDIT: Oh nvm, I think I found it

Comment: That would depend on what system you were using (i.e., PC via Steam, Xbox 360 or PS3).

Comment: Or maybe contact with support ;) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Badass points are described in game as being shared by all your characters. They are based on an achievement system, and are used to buy buffs. If you find a way to get rid of achievements, you can get rid of your points. Presently, I don't think there's a way to do that.

Like most games, some achievements can only be attained through several full runs on the game, and sometimes, by deliberate heavy farming. So, in terms of game completion, there's no reason not to share your account with friends, and the like.

The game does have an option to disable the bonuses you get from badass points, if you are looking for the raw experience.

Also, badass point effectiveness decreases as you spend them on the same attribute bonus, so, to get the most out of them, you should spend them on all bonuses equally.